# Not Found Error (404) with Static files when running from prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, bottle, raspbian

I recently moved from windows to raspberry pi for my app. It loaded at least once but now for the life of me I can't get static files to load again.

If I run the python script from shell as sudo (or without) I get 404 for all static files, dynamic links still work as expected.

If I run it from IDLE logging in as 'pi' it works fine.

Relevant code:

```
from bottle import route, run, get, request, static_file

    @get('/pumps')
    def pumpData():
        return json.dumps(pump.getPumps())

    # root dir
    @route('/<filename>')
    def server_static(filename):
        return static_file(filename, root='')

    # css dir
    @route('/css/<filename>')
    def server_static(filename):
        return static_file(filename, root='css')

    run(host='myip', port=2000, debug=True)
```

What could be causing the issue? I could guess its something to do with permissions but I dont know how I would fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a permission problem.  (That would return a 403.)  It's most likely a path issue.

The good news is: fixing it should be straightforward.  (Famous last words. ;) You should either

1. specify absolute an path as the `root` param to `static_file`, or
2. call `os.chdir()` into the static file root before you call `bottle.run`.

So, this:

```
return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/your/static/file/root')
```

or this:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/your/static/file/root')
run(host='myip', port=2000, debug=True)
```

Comment: That worked! Any idea why the path wasn't an issue when started from IDLE?

Comment: Excellent! Hmm, could have been working earlier due to different current dir? I believe "./" is on the `PATH` by default.

Comment: you can also use os.walk()